# Listening for pod fail in kubernetes java client?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

i'm new to kubernetes i need to write a program that is listening to kubernetes change such as new pod creation or pod deletion. For these i've already the solution but i don't know how to listen for failing of pods, can someone help? I'm using the kubernetes java official client but i can also switch to another language to solve the problem, Thanks

Comment: Your cluster is self managed or managed by some cloud provider? A good start point should be the kubernetes [auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/). PLease describe in more details your cluster and exactly what you want to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the pod status, here you have some examples into https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

You can take this example to get the pod status:

```
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Pod;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1PodList;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ApiException{
        ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
        V1PodList list = api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
            System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
            System.out.println(item.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can watch:

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Namespace;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Watch;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WatchExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ApiException{
        ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();

        Watch<V1Namespace> watch = Watch.createWatch(
                client,
                api.listNamespaceCall(null, null, null, null, null, 5, null, null, Boolean.TRUE, null, null),
                new TypeToken<Watch.Response<V1Namespace>>(){}.getType());

        for (Watch.Response<V1Namespace> item : watch) {
            System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", item.type, item.object.getMetadata().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned by the user Ruben, we can implement a watch. To go even beyond, I have provided an example on how to run health checks too. The following block of code is merely the watch event with the pod status in the MODIFIED case.

```
try (Watch<V1Pod> watch = Watch.createWatch(
        client,
        coreV1Api.listNamespacedPodCall(namespace, null, null, null, null,
                labels, null, null, null, null, Boolean.TRUE, null),
        new TypeToken<Watch.Response<V1Pod>>() {
        }.getType())) {

    for (Watch.Response<V1Pod> eventPod : watch) {
        V1Pod pod = eventPod.object;
        switch (eventPod.type) {
            case "ADDED":
                System.out.println("Pod: " + pod.getMetadata().getName() + " ADDED\n");
                break;
            case "MODIFIED":
                System.out.println("Pod: " + pod.getMetadata().getName() + " has been MODIFIED\n");
                // Check to see the current status of the pod
                if (!pod.getStatus().getPhase().equals("Running")){
                    System.out.println("Pod: " + pod.getMetadata.getName() + " is now " + pod.getStatus());
                }
                break;
            case "DELETED":
                System.out.println("Pod: " + pod.getMetadata().getName() + " has been DELETED\n");
            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown Event Occurred: " + eventPod.type + "\n");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Kubernetes [defines the different statuses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) that you could implement as part of the health check condition.